# when i try to use npm to install some package in my win8, it always gives me error like this

Tags: node.js, npm

[image]

This example shows the [bcrypt](/questions/tagged/bcrypt) package. But my friends tells me it installs ok on a [macbook](/questions/tagged/macbook). Anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

[node.bcrypt.js](https://github.com/ncb000gt/node.bcrypt.js) depends on [node-gyp](https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp) to compile it's native modules. Unfortunately, node-gyp has further dependencies on Python and Visual Studio C++, which are **not** installed on Windows by default. You'll need to install those dependencies manually before node-gyp will work. See the [node-gyp installation guide](https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#installation) for further details.

[node.bcrypt.js is well-known for being hard to install on Windows](https://github.com/ncb000gt/node.bcrypt.js/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=Windows). An alternative, much easier work-around is to use [bcrypt.js](https://github.com/dcodeIO/bcrypt.js), which is a drop-in replacement for node.bcrypt.js. It has no dependency on node-gyp, as it has no native modules.